# Can not connect to S3 in the AppCloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

Before I executed the following commands I set up AWS by using the aws configure command. For the region I tried "Nil" and "None".

```
C:\Windows\system32>aws s3api --endpoint-url https://ds41s3-scs.swisscom.com create-bucket --bucket aws_tst

Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ds41s3-scs.swisscom.com/aws_tst"

C:\Windows\system32>aws s3api --endpoint-url https://ds31s3.swisscom.com create-bucket --bucket aws_tst

('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefusedError(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))
```

As you can see I tried the endpoint url that can be found in the AppCloud docu as well as the url that is given in my service key. I also tried other ways to connect to the service. For example the S3 manager but I keep getting this error. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, I tried the aws cli on os x. Without configuring the region I got the error: Connection aborted. Instead configuring the region to "eu-west-1" it worked perfectly. Could you try to run aws configure adding the region? The correct endpoint to use is "https://ds31s3.swisscom.com". I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, it works! Do you know what regions are implemented in Swisscoms S3 or does it not matter which region I choose to store confidential files since those regions are just names? Those files should stay in the AppCloud and not leave the Swisscom network. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Very good happy to hear that. I don't know exactly which other regions can be used, but since the Appcloud resides in one region it should not matter. You're welcome!